# Inequalities in the $H^s$ norm

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the appendix of Burq-Gérard-Tzvetkov: [Multilinear eigenfunction estimates and global existence for the three dimensional NLS equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409015) and there are some inequalities that they used and I am not able to prove them:

In the display (A.4) of page 53, why
$$  \|g\|^{1/4}_{L^2} \|g\|^{3/4}_{H^2}\leq C n^{1/2}E_n(g)$$

where $E_n(g)=(n^2\|g\|^2_{L^2}+\frac{1}{n^2} \|\Delta g\|^2_{L^2})^{1/2}$.
It seems to me like they are using Young's inequality, but I am not able to figure out how...

Second, between the display (A.6) and the display (A.7) why
$$\|\nabla g \|_{H^{3/4}}\leq C n^{3/2}E_n(g) ?$$

Comment: If you haven't seen the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) you can just use the Fourier transform version of $H^2$-norm, split the $1+\omega^2$, and finally use weighted means inequality.  Similar for the last part.

Comment: @user10354138 By using for example the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality in the second inequality, one obtains $\|\nabla g\|_{H^{3/4}}\leq C\|\Delta g\|_{L^2}^{7/8}\|g\|_{L^2}^{1/8}$ But I am still not able to see how the $E_n(g)$ appears...

Comment: That follows from either Young's inequality or weighted means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the first inequality is indeed just the Young inequality for the product. If you write $a = \|g\|_{L^2}$ and $b = \|\Delta g\|_{L^2}$ then squaring everything, the inequality you want to prove can be written
  $$
  a^{1/2}\,(a^2+b^2)^{3/4} \leq C\,n\,(n^2\,a^2 + b^2 / n^2).
  $$
  Since $(a^2+b^2)^{3/4} \leq a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}$, it follows that
  $$
  a^{1/2}\,(a^2+b^2)^{3/4} \leq a^{2} + a^{1/2}b^{3/2}.
  $$
  Now $a^{2} \leq n\,n^2\,a^2$ because $n\geq 1$, while by Young's inequality
  $$
  a^{1/2}b^{3/2} = n\,(na)^{1/2}\,(b/n)^{3/2} \leq n\left(\tfrac{n^2a^2}{4} + \tfrac{3\,b^2}{4\,n^2}\right),
  $$
  hence
  $$
  a^{1/2}\,(a^2+b^2)^{3/4} \leq \tfrac{5}{4}\,n\, \left(n^2a^2 + \tfrac{b^2}{n^2}\right).
  $$
- Your second inequality follows similarly, noting indeed first that by interpolation $\|\nabla g\|_{H^{3/4}} \leq C\,(a + a^{1/4}\,b^{7/8})$ and so you get the result since
  $$
  a^{1/8}\,b^{7/8} = n^{3/4} (na)^{1/8}\,(b/n)^{7/8}.
  $$
  leads to $\|\nabla g\|_{H^{3/4}} \leq C\,n^{3/4} \,E_n(g)$.